# Normalize address in database

Tags: database, schema, erd

I am working on normalizing a table which contains institute column that contains institute id, institute name, and institute city, all in one single column.
First normal form says that every column should be atmoic.
So to make it normal, I created a new table and assign insituteID to previous table (from which I am linking the new table), and this instituteID would be the primary key in new table.
So my question is, Is I am going the right way?
I searched it on the net but couldn't get satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could these values come in one single column. This is naturally a single relation (table). And all these attributes are atomic. So in my opinion this relation is already in 1st NF.
- An institute can not have more than one id, id column is atomic.
- An institute can not have more than one name so institute name is also atomic.
- An institute can not be situated in more than one city so institute city is also atomic

Comment: U r right. But as I said, this new table is added by me. Because in original table, this single column does not make sense.
So again, back to my question, is it a correct approach to create a new table??

Comment: I got the data from net, so it was there in this format i.e. code, name and city in one column. That is why I created new table

Comment: But you have not provided any information about the new table. As far as the above table is concerned it is already normalized.

Comment: No you shouldn't create any new table in the scenario mentioned